# How long do I need from landing in Zurich to get to a connecting flight to Dublin?

Tags: schengen, transit, irish-citizens, zrh

How long do I need from landing in Zurich to be able to get to a connecting flight to Dublin? I will be arriving at Zurich airport on a flight from Geneva.

I have an Irish passport.

---

I am arriving from Geneva. The flight connection time is 50 minutes.

Comment: If you know the gates, this may help https://www.swiss.com/gr/en/fly/airport/zurich-airport

Comment: Of course, we’ll consider that both flights are on a single ticket. Otherwise it’s a very very bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

According to several different threads ([1](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k7534932-55_min_layover_at_Zurich_Airport_possible-Air_Travel.html), [2](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g188113-i337-k10517787-45_minute_connection_time_at_Zurich_airport-Zurich.html), [3](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g188113-i337-k11622425-Is_50_min_connecting_time_enough_at_Zurich_airport-Zurich.html)) people routinely have short connections in Zurich of around 45-55 minutes without an issue. And the [airport themselves](https://www.swiss.com/il/EN/fly/airport/zurich-airport#t-page=pane2) show a graph of how long it takes to move in between any two gates, the longest being 30 minutes. So as long as the flight is not delayed you should have no issue.

If you have booked this trip all together then it is the airlines responsibility to get you to your final destination and they will put you onto the next flight.